# Is there any possible way to use this code without specifying an id using html?

Tags: html

My Code: https://jsfiddle.net/n0s5o9tw/2/

My question is, is there any possible way to use this code without an id?

Is there another way to do this code without using, getElementById?

```
<div onclick="thevid=document.getElementById('thevideo'); thevid.style.display='block'; this.style.display='none'">

<a style="display:inline-block;background-color:orange; width: 256px; height: 256px; cursor: pointer; border-radius:50px; border: 5px solid #33B927;"></a>
</div>

<div id="thevideo" style="display: none;">
<iframe width="256" height="256" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/'" style="background-color:#000000;width: 256px; height: 256px; cursor: pointer; border-radius:50px; border: 5px solid #711B93;"frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: You could use a class, or select the div relative to another element on teh page. What are you actually trying to accomplish here, why not use the id?

Comment: Can you show me examples of how to do this in jsfiddle?

Comment: @htmlcoding3456, can you do some research on your end?

Comment: If you're able to show me, then that's how I'll learn.

Comment: The idea here is that when someone gives you a suggestion that you don't understand, you should make an attempt to understand it on your own rather than spam your own topic with the same question over again begging someone to explain it. It will be very difficult for you to learn how to code if you are not willing to problem solve at all on your own.  Stack Overflow is a good resource, but you need to be willing to learn in order to get the most out of it. You could have easily googled this concept instead of waiting hours for a response http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_elements.asp

Comment: The code you're showing is bad practice and inexperience on many levels, I'm afraid the above commenters are right in that you should begin somewhere else for your own benefit.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `getElementByClass`